# Serialization error in service stack when using client library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack REST service (PUT and POST) which I have tested with fiddler and if no errors are raised I return

```
new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Now I am testing the same REST service with the service stack client, I have:

```
var client = new XmlServiceClient("url"));
client.Post<ChangeServerLicenseDto>("", new ChangeServerLicenseDto()
         {ServerName = model.ServerName});
```

and I get the exception on the REST service when I do

```
    return new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

and the error raised is :

```
      500 (Error in line 1 position 76. Expecting element 'ChangeServerLicense'
      from namespace ''.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'HttpStatusCode',
      namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net'.)
```

My client code is in a MVC action method (POST).

My datacontract for the RestService is :

```
[DataContract(Name = "ChangeServerLicense", Namespace = "")]
[RestService("url", "POST", "application/xml")]
public class ChangeServerLicenseDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ServerName", Order = 1)]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention of signalling a successful response is to return an empty Response DTO (which by default returns a 200 OK). Also `Send<TResponse>(...)` does a POST so if you don't want to include the url in the request, use `Send` which will **POST** the request to the [automatic pre-defined routes](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes):

```
var client = new XmlServiceClient("url"));
client.Send<ChangeServerLicenseDtoResponse>(
    new ChangeServerLicenseDto {ServerName = model.ServerName});
```

Otherwise if you still want to use `.Post<T>(...)` include the URL for the custom route where your services is mounted.

Note: I generally dislike using `Dto` suffixes on DTOs which are the most important API in your service - I explain in a [bit more detail why here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/servicestack/OsBi5wyg5-A/4VHllY9jK_MJ).

Comment: Thanks, in my haste to get this working, I did not read the first generic parameter was a response type. I am now returning an empty DTO (SuccessCommandResponse) as I do not expect my posts and puts to be commands which do not return data. Thanks once again.